# Do the groups involved in geometrical isomerism have to be in similar planes to show geometrical isomerism?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, isomers, cis-trans-isomerism

In my textbook, under the topic "Conditions for geometrical isomerism", the following has been given:

> Groups responsible to show geometrical isomerism must be nearly in the same plane.

Is this statement really true? Because, we are well aware that disubstituted cycloalkanes which show geometrical isomerism are not planar. Eg: 1,2-Dimethylcyclopropane

Kindly explain with examples.

Comment: There is nothing to explain. People make blunders, and an example you've just found yourself.

Comment: It is a poor definition but it is formally correct. What is important is rigidity. Two points always identify plane (s). There must be a plane *on which the groups cannot rotate, ie at the end a bond with rotation.

Comment: In my comment above "with" reads "without rotation", of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have geometrical isomers you need a **structurally rigid bond**. This bond can be double and this is a case where groups are in the same plane:

[image]

Or can be a cyclic compound where the  carbon-carbon single bond is restricted(2 examples below):

1st example:

[image]

2nd example:

[image]

Your textbook definition is incomplete and I wouldn't use the word "must" there.

Comment: The captions of both structures in your first example is identical. Yet 2nd set of that example is 1,2-dimethylcyclopropane. It has both *cis*- and *trans*-isomers. Please change the captions accordingly.